# How to prove an upper bound inequality for the $l_1$ norm of $Ax$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am stuck trying to show the following inequality, which seems obvious but I am not sure how to prove formally:

$||Ax||_1 \le \sum^{n}_{j=1} (\sum^{m}_{i=1} |a_{ij}|)|x_j|$

for any $A \in \mathbb R^{m × n} $ and $x \in \mathbb R^n$

I am only supposed to use the $l_1$ vector norm definition in the proof.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried writing down $$||Ax||_1$ as a sum and using the triangle inequality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of matrix-vector multiplication and $\ell^1$-norm:
\begin{align}
\|Ax\|_1 &= \left\|\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}x_j, \ldots \sum_{j=1}^n a_{mj}x_j\right)\right\|_1\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m \left|\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j\right|\\
&\le \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}||x_j|\\
&\le \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^m|a_{ij}|\right)|x_j|.
\end{align}